# Is it possible to use Firebase Messaging with Google Analytics in Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I started using Firebase Cloud Messaging for an Android app and now I'm trying to add Google Analytics (not Firebase analytics) to the same app.

The problem is that when creating google-services.json for Analytics, it ignores FCM. I'm using the same google account to create both json files.

I read that when enabling the second service (in this case Analytics) the json should update adding both Messaging and Analytics but maybe this only works within Firebase services?

I could use Firebase Analytics and actually that's what Google recommends, but is it possible to use both Google Analytics with Firebase services?

Comment: Are you adding GA to an existing Firebase project or are you adding Firebase to an existing Google Developers project with GA?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I'm trying to add GA to an existing Firebase project, but when creating GA project and tracking number it creates a new google-services.json with different properties than FCM's json. For example, project_number and project_id are different in both jsons

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback I'll notify the team of this issue.

Comment: Steve's answer actually worked, it was just confusing that the jsons had different properties. I ignored all GA json properties and added "analytics_service" to FCM json

Comment: @ArthurThompson what about adding Firebase to existing GA project?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging and Google Analytics in the same app.  I would suggest using the json file generated by Firebase and merging in the following object into the "services" object :

```
 "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "<your tracking id>"
          }
        },
```

Comment: It worked! I just had to wait some minutes for the GA dashboard to update. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me too. I implemented Admob Native ads but i want to use GA too. Admob and Firebase has different google-services.json files. This solved my problem

Comment: It worked for me too, however the "project_number" on the project info is different in both json files, but it works,

Comment: Where I can find this tracking id?