# Using google analytics with fcm cloud messaging

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am implementing google cloud messaging with FCM and want to integrate with another application .That android application uses google analytics and uses a **google-services.json** .

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "911170071927",
    "project_id": "b-ye-biyeta"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "testID",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "test.test"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "current_key"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "UA-99587937-4"
          }
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

.But i hava a **google-services.json** file in my project for FCM.

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "133757610052",
    "firebase_url": "https://myfirstfcmproject-6e8d2.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "myfirstfcmproject-6e8d2",
    "storage_bucket": "myfirstfcmproject-6e8d2.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:133757610052:android:98ebe0f1cafb29f6",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.akash.myapplication"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "133757610052-5qctmaccs09p8g42nengtm7mt60n167u.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyAegW-Owdx0ReDCjx3S3iP1ye8r8AYAAFs"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Both needs to be same placed in same module .How to place both **google-services.json** file in same application with same google account .

Thanks

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716425/4665578